# how to prove two propositions in summation formula

Tags: linear-algebra

This question is from a book writing by Wu-Yi Hsiang which is not a homework assignment.

It is about summation formula for a polynomial $f(x)$, $\deg(f(x))=l$，we set

$g_k(x)=\frac{1}{k!}\prod\limits_{i=0}^{k-1}(x-i)$, in which k means the power of polynomial.

Clearly, $g_k(i)=0, 0\leqslant i \leqslant k-1$, $g_k(k)=1$

Define, 
$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}g_k(i)=S_{g_k}(n)$$.

as summation formula

$$\bigtriangleup f(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$$

as difference operator

prove two propositions

proposition 1：

$$S_{g_k}(x)=g_{k+1}(x)=\frac{1}{(k+1)!}\prod\limits_{i=0}^{k}(x-i)$$

While  author just use this is following prove , maybe it is trivial for author, I can not understand how to get this formula

proposition 2：

$$f(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^lc_kg_k(x)$$

which

$$c_k=\bigtriangleup^k f(0)$$

Author said the $f(x)$ can be uniquely determined by the combination of $g_k(x)$，I want to prove this but failed. Then he proves how to get coefficients and I understand that.

Thanks.

Comment: I already know the power of sum of the k power polynomial is k+1

Comment: Nicely typeset, but what was the question again? Are you just asking us to prove some claim? The one about $g_{k+1}(x)$? Or the formula for $c_k$? Where is this question from? It might even be a homework assignment, and that presses people's buttons. I think we need a bit of context to understand exactly what the question is. It may help, if you take a look at [the guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619).